# Enable proguard automatically while creating new project in Android

Tags: android, eclipse, security, apk, android-proguard

Many times after building an app and uploading it to play store I realize that I haven't guarded the apk using proguard feature provided by android and anyone can decompile the app using various tools to get my app's source code. So is it possible that whenever i create a new project the proguard feature is automatically enabled and my app's source code can be secure?

Answer (score 0):

For obfuscation just add to project.properties file in android project the following line:

```
proguard.config=proguard.cfg
```

see details in android's development page [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html)

Comment: I have gone through the page bro. It says that we have to enable progaurd from the file project.properties by uncommenting the line "proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt". But i am asking something else bro. I am asking for some automatic way to unable progaurd without uncommenting that line. Or I can say that without manually uncommenting that line enable the progaurd automatically.

Comment: that has more to do with eclipse, rather then android

Answer (score 0):

Probably you will have to right a custom ant build script which throws an error when proguard property is not set in properties.To write custom ant build script visit this link:
http://www.androidengineer.com/2010/06/using-ant-to-automate-building-android.html